# Wrong key constants in ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to get familiar with ncurses and I have a problem - the constants such as KEY_LEFT seem to be wrong.

For example, I'm trying to catch keyboard arrows. Should be as simple as

```
while (ch = getch()){
  if (ch == KEY_LEFT)
    foo();
}
```

But that does not work. I had the `ch` written out and it says this - left arrow is 68, right 67, up 65, down 66.

That wouldn't be such a problem, but when trying to catch mouse events, it goes bad. Leftclicking the terminal gives me values from 33 to 742, least when clicking upper left corner, most when clicking bottom right corner. What the hell?

This is my whole main, just in case

```
int main(void){
initscr();


start_color();
init_pair(1, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_WHITE);
init_pair(2, COLOR_RED, COLOR_RED);

cbreak();

//printw("Hai!\n");
noecho();
int width;
int height;

getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);

int posx = 30;
int posy = 30;

const char* str = "   ";
const char* hint = "ch = %d";

curs_set(0);


mousemask(BUTTON1_CLICKED, NULL);

unsigned int ch = 0;
while (ch = getch()) {
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvprintw(0, 0, hint, ch);
    mvdelch(posy,posx);
    mvdelch(posy, posx);
    mvdelch(posy, posx);
    switch (ch) {
        case 68:
            if (posx > 0) posx--;
            //mvprintw(1,0,"LEFT");
            break;

        case 67:
            if (posx < width) posx++;
            break;

        case 65:
            if (posy > 0) posy--;
            break;

        case 66:
            if (posy < height) posy++;
            break;

        case KEY_MOUSE:
            MEVENT event;
            if (getmouse(&event)==OK){
                posx = event.x;
                posy = event.y;
            }
    }

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    mvprintw(posy, posx, str);

    refresh();
}

endwin();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As (almost) always a look in the manual helps. Taking a look at `man getch`

> Function Keys
>          The  following  function keys, defined in curses.h, might be returned by getch
>          if keypad has been enabled.  Note that not all of these are necessarily support‐
>          ed on any particular terminal.

it seems you missed

```
keypad (stdscr, TRUE);
```

in your program. At least it doesn't occur in the snippet you posted.

Comment: damn. I know I have to call it, but didn't notice it was missing ._. Thanks

Comment: Note that you also need to enable the keypad in order to use the mouse -- something that does not appear to be documented anywhere.

Comment: Another note: When using `keypad` and want to capture all keys, you should use `int ch` not `char ch`, because some key codes are bigger than 255.